# Can't compile ftpupload.c

Tags: c++, compilation, g++

I'm trying to compile [ftpupload.c](https://github.com/curl/curl/blob/master/docs/examples/ftpupload.c) with command `g++ -o program ftpupload.c`, but I get the following error:

```
ftpupload.c: In function ‘size_t read_callback(char*, size_t, size_t, void*)’:
ftpupload.c:57:50: error: invalid conversion from ‘void*’ to ‘FILE* {aka _IO_FILE*}’ [-fpermissive]
   size_t retcode = fread(ptr, size, nmemb, stream);
                                                  ^
In file included from ftpupload.c:22:0:
/usr/include/stdio.h:646:15: note:   initializing argument 4 of ‘size_t fread(void*, size_t, size_t, FILE*)’
 extern size_t fread (void *__restrict __ptr, size_t __size,
               ^~~~~
```

Comment: This is compiling a C file as C++. Is this what you want to do?

Comment: This is one of the things where C and C++ are different. That implicit pointer cast is OK in C, but not OK in C++. The solution depends on what you are actually intending to do with this C (!) source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is compiling a C source file as C++. C++ is stricter when it comes to implicit conversions and does not allow an implicit conversion from a `void*` to any other pointer ([source](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pointer)):

> Pointer to object of any type can be implicitly converted to pointer to void (optionally cv-qualified); the pointer value is unchanged. The reverse conversion, which requires static_cast or explicit cast, yields the original pointer value: [..]

To resolve this, either use a C compiler or add a cast:

```
size_t retcode = fread(ptr, size, nmemb, static_cast<FILE*>(stream));
```

It is not recommended, but if this line needs to be bilingual C and C++, you could use a C-style cast:

```
size_t retcode = fread(ptr, size, nmemb, (FILE*) stream);
```

On a side note: `ftpupload.c` does not contain a standalone program and will not fully compile even with the cast. The best solution depends on why you'd like to compile this file in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Add an explicit cast:

```
size_t retcode = fread(ptr, size, nmemb, (FILE *)stream);
```

C++ is more strict in pointer conversion than C.

Comment: On the other hand, if this file comes from some external source modifying it might bring trouble with the file getting updated, as one would have to re-patch it again and again. Probably rather compile as is as C with the appropriate compiler and have the famous `extern "C"` guards when including the header (adding them around the include, if not contained in the original header).

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you are trying to compile C file using C++ compiler. So you must use gcc command instead of g++. The compiler report belongs to type casting. Stream variable must be casted to FILE*.